# How to reference specific td(s) to get their values from an html table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 and I have an array of values I'm getting from an html table.  What I'm trying to do is get the value from a specific td when the user clicks on the row.  I used this code to get all the td values from the particular row:

jsp code:

```
<tr>
<s:iterator value="model.NameList">
<tr>
   <td align=center><s:property value="message.substring(0,125)"/></td>
   <td align=center><s:property value="timestamp"/></td>
   <td align=center><s:property value="retryCount"/></td>
   <td align=center><s:property value="specialId"/></td>
...
   </tr>
  </s:iterator> ...
```

**specialId is the td cell value I need to get from each selected row from the click event.**

//Click event code left out.

```
var arr = [];
arr = $(this).find('td').map(function(){     
return this.innerHTML;   
}).get();
```

Then I need to check for a particular cells value using an if block as I loop through the cells in that row.  I hardcoded it as in the code below to get the value, but I need to do this dynamically.

```
$.each(arr, function(i, l){ 
    if(i == 6) { ...
```

So I created an id for the td cell to get that value, but I'm going to need to get this particular cells value from multiple rows so the id by itself wont work.  I need to handle getting the value from the row and then getting it from multiple rows if the user selects more than one row and send that value to Struts2 hidden textboxes.  I'm just using one textbox to start with and that worked.

```
$('#textboxId').val(l); //Set the value to the id of a hidden textbox.
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Since I only need one value from each row, I'm thinking there is a better way to code this, but I also need to allow for n(values) of td's.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show your HTML (or a representative sample), and explain from which cells, and under what conditions, you want to get the value/content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of row you can get the value using something like this:

```
jQuery('table tr').click(function(){
   jQuery('#hiddenInputText').val('jQuery(this).find('#thisone').text()'); 
   //thisone is the id of the id whose value should be fetched
});​
```

say if your textfield is like

```
<s:inputText id="hiddenInputText" />
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/Dv4Dw/1/)

Comment: I had the same click event code, but setting the value your way is much better!  Thanks!

Comment: Alternately and a little easier to read it can be written like this: `alert(jQuery('#thisone', this).text());`

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the parent TD depending on the user's click by using the jquery [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.

**[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s47Uv/1/)**

Here's the sample HTML I'm using:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Foo</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Bar</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

This is the Jquery code, using 1.6.4.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').bind('click',function(){
        var newVal = '<b>You clicked</b>';
        $(this).parent('td').html(newVal);
    });
});​
```

Its not entirely clear what you're asking in your question, so I could have got you wrong. If so, create a jsfiddle for us to better understand your issue.

**EDIT**

Following the edit to your question, this is what you're looking for:

**Example HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Property</td>
        <td>Timestamp</td>
        <td>RetryCount</td>
        <td>SpecialID</td>
    </tr>    
</table>​
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').bind('click',function(){
       alert($(this).children('td').last().text());
    });
});​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s47Uv/3/)**

**Explanation**

You first attach the click handler to `tr` so the user can click anywhere on the row. The click handler looks for all `td` elements within the clicked `tr` (i.e. the children). Of all the children it finds, you tell it to alert the text of the last child (that is what the `.last()` method does).

Comment: Except in my case it's index 6 out of 9 elements, so it's not last.  I used ... to show there was more code that was left out.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard: In that case, instead of `.last()`, you can do `.eq(5)` for the 6th element. (`eq()` is 0-indexed)